# Catch error from lastlog (unix & bash)

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm creating a script to detect which user didn't connect to the server for a while.

So far everything is good but now trying to remove some unwanted entry from the list produced from my script. I would like to add an exception to my script so that when lastlog is called with a non used argument, the ouput isn't printed to the screen.

I've tried somthing like :

```
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR!"
fi
```

But the problem is that lastog is returning 0 on success but simply :

```
lastlog: Unknown user or range: infolog
```

on error. So I cannot catch the exeption.

Here's my code (which is pretty simple)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=../*

for year in 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012
do
    for f in $FILES
    do
        tempUser=${f:3:20}
        userCommand=`lastlog -u $tempUser | grep $year`

        if [ ${#userCommand} != 0 ]   
        then
          echo "$userCommand"
        fi

    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this pretty simply, but on my handy linux box `lastlog` does indeed set a nonzero status for a bad user name:

```
$ if lastlog -u nosuchuser; then echo no error; else echo error; fi
lastlog: Unknown user or range: nosuchuser
error
```

If you're running this in a pipe, the problem is that the "status" of a pipe sequence is the status of the *last* element of the pipeline:

```
$ progA | progB | progC
$ echo $?
```

prints the status for progC.

If you use bash, you can get the status from everything via bash's `PIPESTATUS` array variable:

```
bash$ progA | progB | wc
bash: progB: command not found
bash: progA: command not found
      0       0       0
bash$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
127 127 0
bash$
```

which should get you the rest of the way there.

---

Edit: you might not even care, and just be looking for a way to throw away stderr output from `lastlog`, in which case, consider:

```
$ lastlog 2>/dev/null | grep ...
```